# Unit-testing ExtJS app with Selenium

Tags: unit-testing, extjs, selenium

How do you go about unit-testing ExtJS web apps using Selenium?

Can you point me to some web resources or book regarding this issue?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/107314/any-suggestions-for-testing-extjs-code-in-a-browser-preferably-with-selenium and http://www.sencha.com/blog/2008/11/03/testing-ext-js-ext-gwt-applications-with-selenium/

Answer (score 1):

What pieces of your application are you looking to test using Selenium? Unit testing implies smaller pieces than a full "UI" test, from my perspective. If you're looking to do  true [unit testing](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/unit_testing), you will probably want to pull in some library like [jsUnit](https://github.com/pivotal/jsunit) or [qUnit](http://docs.jquery.com/Qunit) and then just have Selenium run those tests, and then grab the resulting information.

I haven't directly used Selenium to test the view itself, since I've always considered that to be pretty solid, coming directly from the Sencha crew. If you're trying to go down this road, your best bet would probably be to search the official [selenium user group](http://groups.google.com/group/selenium-users). They appear fairly active. The user group would potentially be a good resource for asking questions, as well. While keeping in mind that ExtJS is just a powerful way to alter the DOM in a very dynamic fashion.

...and I just noticed the links off to other pages that have already been provided. Still valid data, so I'm going to post it anyways. :)