# Set Values in combobox for a ExtJS based UI using Selenium

Tags: javascript, extjs, selenium

I have a ExtJS based UI. I have come to know that in ExtJS the combo box is not a real combo box but a combination of input text field, image of drop down box and a list.

Now i am able to identify the control but i am stuck at selecting the value from the list.Coyuld you please help me out in setting the value of "functional currency" from the drop down. Please find the HTML Source code below

```
<input id="bc_lookupcombo-1139-inputEl" type="text" role="combobox" class="x-form-field x-form-text x-form-focus x-field-form-focus x-field-default-form-focus" autocomplete="off" name="reporting_currency" placeholder="Entity Functional Currency" style="width: 100%;">
```

Comment: Could you edit your post to show the code? From the numerous search hits on this site alone, what have you tried?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any suggestions for testing extjs code in a browser, preferably with selenium?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/107314/any-suggestions-for-testing-extjs-code-in-a-browser-preferably-with-selenium)