# How to select a extjs combobox with webdriver and python

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

How can i select this combobox and click to select the options ?
When load that combobox again that always create a new id, so i can't use id.

HTML:

```
<input id="combobox-1168-inputEl" type="text" 
       class="x-form-field x-form-text  x-trigger-noedit x-form-focus x-field-form-focus x-field-default-form-focus"
       autocomplete="off" name="combobox-1168-inputEl"
       readonly="readonly" tabindex="1" 
       aria-invalid="false" data-errorqtip="" 
       style="width: 100%; -webkit-user-select: text;">
```

I'm trying to use xpath looking for the class:

```
teste2 = browser.find_by_xpath("//input[contains(@class,'x-form-field.x-form-text..x-trigger-noedit.x-form-focus.x-field-form-focus.x-field-default-form-focus')]")
```

But it return:

```
In [122]: teste2
Out[122]: []
```

How can I do it ?

Comment: A simple search on SO returns many results. Did you try any of those?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any suggestions for testing extjs code in a browser, preferably with selenium?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/107314/any-suggestions-for-testing-extjs-code-in-a-browser-preferably-with-selenium)

Comment: I could find the element, but my problem now is that phantomjs click() is not working properly. I have found the element and i click on the element but my screenshot beforclick and afterclick are the same. Nothing happens after the click.

Comment: Is this now a new question? Need to see some code, everything else is just guesswork. Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks SiKing. It's a new question, but this one was solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using find_elements_by_xpath, because I have a few elements with the same class, so I used find_elements and used the results as a list and I selected the index that I need.
With this steps I could select and be happy with the results.