# CasperJS to test ExtJS 4.1 application - Ext.getCmp() always returns undefined

Tags: extjs, extjs4, phantomjs, casperjs

I am using capserjs to test my ExtJS 4.1 application. This is how I have made reference to ext.js file

`casperjs test --include=ext-all.js testFile.js`

If I open console tab on chrome developer toolbar & type `Ext.getCmp('id of component');` I get the component back.

But If I do the same thing with in my casperjs test, I always gets undefined.

I was initially trying to get a combobox using `Ext.getCmp()` which returned `undefined`, after that I tried finding textbox, labels using  `Ext.getCmp()` and every-time it returned undefined.

I have also tried to use Component query and even that did not worked.

I also looked at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107314/any-suggestions-for-testing-extjs-code-in-a-browser-preferably-with-selenium) for help but I am unable to produce desired result.

```
.then(function(){

     this.wait(5000, function(){
       this.capture('c:\\temp\\cmb.png');
         console.log('-----' + Ext);
       var sqCombo = Ext.getCmp('country-ddl'); // returns the ComboBox components

       sqCombo.setValue('UK'); // set the value
       sqCombo.fireEvent('select'); // because setValue() doesn't trigger the event
     })

   })
```

**with injectJs()**

```
    casper.start(baseUrl, function() {
      this.echo("TITLE : ====> " + this.getTitle());
    })
  casper.then(function(){
    var inject = this.page.injectJs('ext-all.js');
    if(inject){
      console.log('injected');
    }else{
      console.log('cant inject');
    }

     console.log('evaluating');
     this.evaluate(function(){
       console.log(Ext);
       var v = Ext.getCmp('shadowUser').text;
       this.echo('++++++++++++++++++++' + v);
     });
  })
```

After running the script, I see this on console:

```
   TITLE : ====> Test App
injected
evaluating
Console: [object Object]
Error: TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'Ext.getCmp('shadowUser').text')
Error: Error: Ext.Loader is not enabled, so dependencies cannot be resolved dynamically. Missing required classes: myApp.view.OptionsView, myApp.view.HelpView, myApp.view.SupportView, myApp.view.AdminView
PASS Title is correct
TESTS COMPLETED
```

Comment: @ArtjomB.: Updated the question to show what I am trying to do. I added selenium tag because I am sure lot of people must have faced the same issue.

Comment: I am basically trying to find a combo-box and want to set some value and then fire the select event. Since ext combo-box is not rendered as `select`, I am struggling to find the component. I have included included extjs using `--include` (as shown in my question) option while running the test case. After this I was able to access `Ext` object and I was thinking, I would be able to access all the underlying methods. I wonder what options do I have now to access the combobox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as `--include=<script>` option. It's called [`--includes=<scripts>`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/testing.html#options), but this doesn't help you, because it would inject extjs into the outer context which doesn't has access to the page.

You would need to [inject](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/inject-js.html) the Extjs script when you need it:

```
casper.then(function(){
    this.page.injectJs('ext-all.js');
    ...
});
```

If Extjs is already included in the page (judging by available Ext components) then you don't need to inject anything. You should then be able to use it from the page context:

```
.then(function(){
    this.wait(5000, function(){
        this.capture('c:\\temp\\cmb.png');
        console.log('-----' + Ext);

        this.evaluate(function(){
            var sqCombo = Ext.getCmp('country-ddl'); // returns the ComboBox components

            sqCombo.setValue('UK'); // set the value
            sqCombo.fireEvent('select'); // because setValue() doesn't trigger the event
        });
    })
    .wait(5000, function(){
        this.capture('c:\\temp\\cmb2.png');
    });
})
```

Keep in mind that `Ext` is only available in the page context which can be accessed through the sandboxed [`evaluate()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#evaluate) function.

Comment: Thank you for taking time out and adding the code. Now I understand why `--include` option will not help in my case. I used the code you showed and it looks like, system is not executing `this.evaluate()`. under this function, I have included console.log() and I do not see anything on the console. Am I missing anything ?

Comment: If you're using PhantomJS 2.0.0, then there is a bug which hides errors. Use PhantomJS 1.9.8 or 1.9.7 to see if there are errors. Please register to the `resource.error`, `page.error`, `remote.message` and `casper.page.onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-2_caspererrors-js)). Maybe there are errors.

Comment: I am now using phantomjs version 1.9.8. I have registered hooks for all the errors. I have also updated the question to include all the details about errors I am getting  after including the suggested changes !!

Comment: Of course, it can't find `Ext`, because it is injected in the page context. Use `evaluate()` like I showed it in my answer.

Comment: My apologies for posting wrong code. I have updated the question again !!

Comment: No idea. Does the screenshot show the element that you're interested in? If not, then you should `waitFor()` it. Btw, if it's an Extjs application, then you really don't need to inject Ext again into the page.

Comment: Firstly, Thank you for spending so much time and energy to answer. Yes, the application is extjs application, but if I directly try to access Ext object, the test case always throws exception saying `Ext` is `undefined`. If I explicitly make reference to extjs using `injectJs()` Ext.loader is throwing error. Ext loader automatically loads all the dependency & in my application I am setting its value to true. The control I am trying to access is available. I can confirm that as i have taken screenshot. If I try to take screenshot inside `evaluate()` nothing happens.

Comment: You can't take screenshots inside of the page context. `casper` is not available there.